# from django.urls import path ImportError: cannot import name 'path' from 'django.urls'

Tags: python, django

I am very beginner in Python. I have project in Python 3.8 and Django. When I try update my old Django to Django 1.11 i have error:

** from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name 'path' from 'django.urls' (/home/ds/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/**init**.py)**

My file:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from .views import *

urlpatterns = ['',
    path(r'^$', 'go.insurance.views.index'),
    path(r'^abc/', include('go.abc.urls')),
    path(r'^help/', include('go.help.urls')),

    path(r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:

    urlpatterns += ['',
        path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

What i make:

1. update: requirements/base.txt => Django==1.11.29
2. /mnt/c/Project/.venvs/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
3. /mnt/c/Project/.venvs/bin/pip3 install django==1.11
4. /.venvs/bin/python3 manage.py runserver in folder requrements

When i run my app i have error:
./.venvs/bin/python3 manage.py runserver

I have error:

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fdc2c9b91f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/mnt/c/Project/go/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name 'path' from 'django.urls' (/mnt/c/Project/.venvs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/__init__.py)
```

How can i repair it? Pleasae help me :)

Comment: Why are you using Django 1.11 for a new project while you can use the latest which is 4.2?

Comment: I try update old project to 4.2. I want update 1.8 to 1.11, then 1.11 to 2, 2 to 3 and 3 to 4 :)

Comment: You can go from 1.8 to 3 without too much problems. I had to do this with one project. Of course there will be changes, but they can be managed. And I assume that moving to the current version (5.0) should work too.